# Change curl on stream_context_create

Tags: php, curl

Pls, help me to get data with stream_context_create.
With curl work that:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ecdhe_rsa_aes_128_gcm_sha_256');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        $curlError = curl_error($curl);        
        $result = json_decode($out, true);   
        curl_close($curl);
```

I try this:

```
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peername' => false

    ),
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' =>
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('$url', false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

But get false. What in my code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the decision:

```
$opts = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
            ),
            'http' => array(
                'timeout' => 5,
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' =>
                    'Content-type: Content-type: application/json',
                'ignore_errors' => true,
                'max_redirects' => 0
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $out = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $result = json_decode($out, true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).